# Cannot connect to MongoDB database using dotenv and mongoose because parameter is not a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, dotenv

I'm trying to use dotenv and mongoose to connect my node.js code to my mongodb database, but keep getting the error: `The 'uri' parameter to 'openUri()' must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to 'mongoose.connect()' or 'mongoose.createConnection()' is a string.`

Here's my code:
*connect.js*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = (url) => {
    return mongoose.connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology:true
    })
}

module.exports = connectDB
```

*.env*

```
MONGO_URI = 'mongodb+srv://anousheh1:xxxxxxx@cluster0.xqrivwh.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

*app.js*

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const tasks = require('./routers/tasks')
const connectDB = require('./db/connect')
require('dotenv').config()
const find = require('./routers/.env')

// Middleware
app.use(express.json())

app.use('/api/v1/tasks', tasks)

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Task Manager App')
})


const port = 3000
const start = async () => {
    try{
        await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI)
        app.listen(port, console.log(`Server is listening on part ${port}`))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(process.env.MONGO_URI)
        console.log(typeof(MONGO_URI))
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}

start()
```

I'm not sure why, in the error section, `console.log(process.env.MONGO_URI)` is undefined, since when I output the type, it does say its a string?

This is my first time using mongoDB so I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but not sure what is going wrong?

Comment: Why it is named `x.env`? it should be `.env`, you need to refer [dotenv npm docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: @turivishal I've just changed it from `x.env` to `.env`, but am still getting the same errors as before

Comment: you need to put this file in the root directory, as i said you need to refer docs.

Comment: @turivishal Thank you so much! It works as expected now that I've moved it to the root directory